# Is there an equivalent of memory mapping baked data structures (the way you might in C++) in Java?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, virtual-machine, mmap

I have a massive data structure that needs to load, effectively, instantly. It's many terabytes of data - a graph, in fact. A buttload of nodes with links to other nodes. This data structure needs to be baked in such a way that I can stand up a service can access any part of it without a multi-millisecond startup delay or overburdensome per-access times.

In the C++ world, I'd pre-bake the data structure into a file. There are tricks that would then allow me to map that file to a specific virtual address, allowing me to even pre-bake pointers (though, it is possible to replace pointers with offsets and map wherever the OS put it.) I'd then memmap the file and the load would be effectively done. Everything would be instantly available the same way a swapped-out page is.

Java doesn't make it as easy. At best, I could mmap the file, then look up nodes Java data structures in the virtual machine and, having failed to find them there, load them on-demand from the map. I'm not as happy with this solution as it will generate a lot more swapping. It would also require more memory if nodes' sizes are non-constant.

In short, if I needed to pack a many-TB+ sized data structure in a file in a way that it could be directly referenced in Java, how would I do it?

Comment: Yes. [`MappedByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) is exactly what you seek.

Comment: MappedByteBuffer is just the quick access to the disk file - it misses the abstraction I need from C/++ where the representation of the data structure is itself contained within the file so I don't have to translate it to a copy of itself to use it within Java. Or am I misunderstanding something about it? For example, in C++, I could mmap the file to a specific address and from that point forward, the entire data structure is complete, constructed, valid, and accessible via virtual memory.

Comment: This is not an answer, but maybe native linkage would be the solution and doing the mapping in C++ be the solution? Java by design tries to avoid such low-level concepts such as pointers, however there's also https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html , so maybe that + some usage of Serializable would be enough?

Comment: @Sniggerfardimungus Java can't do that. `MappedByteBuffer` is the closest you can get.

Comment: @AdamKotwasinski You read my mind. I've considered it, but we're very much a Java & Python shop. As much as I like C++ and realize it would be perfect for this application, I want to avoid having to add support for a third language in our compilation/packaging/testing/deployment process. =~(

Comment: When you're to the level of "multi-terabyte graph dataset", sometimes you have to accept the cost of additional tooling to make necessary operations possible.

Comment: You might have a look into [Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/) (for ideas; or maybe just use it) which is a huge project around the idea of multi-language zero-copy communication. It's focusing on columnar-data (which might even be natural with *sparse matrix formats*) though (where the schema-serialization is based on google's flatbuffers) and documentation might not be it's strength (especially the Java parts). But with my limited understanding, i won't guarantee it's 100% zero-copy in regards c++ <-> java. Imho, Java is really pain-inducing there...